# jax-ws client don't reuse classes

Tags: java, web-services, jax-ws

I've created webservice client with wsimport tool with authentication. This ws client is working fine but i've monitorized application with visual vm and i've seen that every time that ws is called, number of loaded classes increments. If I call webservice so much, the memory used increased too. I think that classes generated by wsimport are not reusinging.

I'm using:
-tomcat 7.0.27 
-jdk_1.6.0_23

Comment: We can't help you like this. You need to post more details. Is it loading classes or generating instances?

Comment: I don't  know. Only that I know is that in visualvm monitor for loaded classes starts with 10k classes loaded and everytime that webservice is invoked increase number of clases about 4000.
See the classes loaded graphic http://postimg.org/image/r0dixt59h/